# Access variable in nodejs from ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, local-storage, ejs

I want to access a variable declared and initialized in my.ejs file within script tag, inside my nodejs app.js server file. Is it possible?if yes then how?

EXAMPLE:
my.ejs
`<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> var num = 2; </script>`

(I cant use localstorage as it wont allow me to communicate between two different files)
Can i do this without mongodb database.
(I cant create another javascript exteral file as it wont serve the purpose i want)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a variable like this to your ejs file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const num = 42;
    res.render('my', { num: num });
});

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> var num = <%= num %>; </script>
```

Comment: Hello, the thing is I want to access variable declared inside ejs file (within script tag)and want to use that variable inside nodejs file. (the one u have mentioned is opposite)_ Thankyou